# Heroku shotdown?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I create a project(Node.js) on Heroku that is for calling api.

It is working for a long time.

But I find my api is not working today.

Call my api on postman get the result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Application Error</title>
        <style media="screen">
          html,body,iframe {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          html,body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I re deploy my project to Heroku, but it is still not working.

I have no idea why happens like this suddently.

Any one knows what is going on with Heroku ?

If I tyep heroku logs shows like this error:

```
2019-01-25T04:21:21.830998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path= "/api/main?city=TaipeiEast" host=obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com request_id=78591079-61f3-4ac3-a6d4-76119425ea69 fwd="60.248.111.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: check the heroku logs.Heroku also sleeps after a period of inactivity

Comment: Thanks for reply.  It looks like not sleeping problem. My project account is payment account.
I type heroku logs show the message I update in my question.  Do you have any idea ?

Comment: sorry.I faced this kind of problem when the config was bad.But you are saying it was running for long time.I don't think config issue is the case here.Check for versions compatibility

Comment: What kind of type version do you mean ?  May be omething like Warning: heroku update available from 7.18.10 to 7.19.4 is the problem ?

Comment: What the...Heroku.  It is working now suddently.... No more problem. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yes heroku sleeps when you are not using atleast in my case.It works after some time when you send the first request.